# Identifying which range a number falls into

Tags: matlab

Given a set number of ranges:

```
a =

    32225   52259
    52260   70794
    70795   91459
    91460   95409
```

And a single value `x = 61450` - is there a way to determine within which range x falls **without** using a loop to check each possibility? The answer in this case would be `2` as 61450 falls within the second range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use

```
res = find(x >= a(1,:) & x < a(2,:));
```

Comment: I would recommend adding `=` to one of the sides.

Comment: @Anna If the ranges are always increasing and contiguous, `result = sum(x>=a(:,1));` this also works

Comment: I'd like to see a time trial, as I suspect @LuisMendo 's suggestion is faster.

Comment: @LuisMendo  you won!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for taking the time to do the benchmarking

Answer (score 5):

OK, did one :-).

```
foo = [1;round(1e5*rand(1000,1))];
foop = [ foo(2:end)+1;1e6];

x = 1e5*rand(1,1);
tic
for j = 1:1000

    bardro = find(x >= foo & x <= foop);
end
tocdro = toc;

tic;
for j = 1:1000
    barlui = sum(x >=foo);
end
toclui  = toc;

>> tocdro
tocdro =
    0.0113
>> toclui
toclui =
    0.0047
```

We have a winner!